# How to create an average polygon from multiple one

Tags: qgis, distance, average, driving

I have in a layer multiple polygons representing for 1 point the potential driving distance in 1 hour like this:

[image: Polygon]

For each white cross I have 4 different polygons (based on different driving date/time)
[image: Layer Desc]
For each layers the attribute table is like this :
[image: Attribute table]
And I need to create an 'average' polygon of this to determinate with all the date the reachable geography to calculate all the customer in the region I can reach.

If I merge all the polygon I'll only have the largerest region and not the average of the four.

How can I do this?
I'm in the right way or not?